# Does Realtime database has atomic increment method for Flutter like ServerValue.increment?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

Transaction is an atomic process but that means we need to read the data prior to incrementing it.

We can easily implement `ServerValue.increment(1)` in Node.js but in Flutter we only have `ServerValue.timestamp` according to the documentation [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/ServerValue-class.html) although the [Google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue) has it

And so far I search I haven't found anything yet. Am I missing something?

Comment: If it hasn't made it to Flutter yet, file a feature request.  https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for your fast response

Comment: No need for a repost of the issue on Github: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2437