# Flutter RealtimeDatabase ServerValue.Increment

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I could not find the function in Flutter to Increment an int value in the realtime DB.

I'm currently using a cloud function to perform the task, but unfortunately, I need a lower latency for this part of the app and cloud functions are not providing the best experience due it's delays + cold start. I would rather use the Firebase Library to do the task and reduce the waiting times.

Has anyone ever done that for the Realtime Db in Flutter and could point me in the right direction?

Thanks :)

Comment: As Doug said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275901/does-realtime-database-has-atomic-increment-method-for-flutter-like-servervalue): This feature hasn't landed in the Flutter library yet: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has not landed in the Flutter bindings for the Realtime Database yet. You can track progress on the feature request (or contribute to it) [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2437).

Comment: Ah ok, will keep monitoring. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

It's available now. You can use ServerValue.increment() as follows:

```
  db.child('path')
    .set(ServerValue.increment(_intValue);
```